# How do professors see the German grades?

Tags: grades, germany

I am currently doing a master in Germany and I scored 2.7 in one particular course. 
How is 2.7 to the professors? Is it a very bad grade? Is this grade uncommon among students?

Comment: Please specify more what you are asking about! E.g. which subject area you are in, who are those professors (your professors, other professors in the same subject area in Germany, other professors in other subject areas in Germany, professors in the same area outside Germany, other professors in a specific area (e.g. US, UK), etc) and why are those professors looking at your grades, i.e. what are they evaluating you for (e.g. to admit to grad school, to write a letter of recommendation for a scholarship, to offer you an internship in their research lab, etc).

Comment: I would like to know in general how 2.7 is, I am unfamiliar with the German grading system.

Comment: we cannot answer your question about "what a 2.7 is "without some details what you mean by it! It sounds like maybe you are asking how good a 2.7 is in terms of an average grade and how many students get a grade better/worse than 2.7? The answer then will depend hugely on the subject area you are enquiring about. To give you a rough idea 1.0 is the best grade and 4.0 is the lowest passing mark. And here is a *very* rough "translation" of German grades. But these sort of charts are nigh meaningless without e.g. specificying subject https://www.studyineurope.eu/study-in-germany/grades

Answer (score 1):

That differs a lot by discipline. If you are doing law, then that is a fine grade, if you are doing sociology, not so much.

Comment: A more complete answer might help educate the rest of us about the meaning here. As it is, it offers little insight.

Comment: How about Science?